# How to add a picture next to a table?

Tags: html

```
<style>

table.greyGridTable {
  border: 2px solid #2196F3;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table.greyGridTable td, table.greyGridTable th {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px 4px;
}
table.greyGridTable tbody td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
}
table.greyGridTable td:nth-child(even) {
  background:  #2196F3;
}
table.greyGridTable thead {
  background: #2196F3;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #333333;
}
table.greyGridTable thead th {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #333333;
}
table.greyGridTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.greyGridTable tfoot {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  border-top: 4px solid #333333;
  background:  #2196F3 ;
}
table.greyGridTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}

</style>
<style>
.Pa_Kreisi {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: top;
}
.Pa_Labi {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: top;
}
</style>

<div class="Pa_Kreisi">
    <table class="greyGridTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Atsēgas vārdi kurus meklēt mūsu mājas lapā:</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td>Meklēt iespējams caur logu lapas augšējā, labajā stūrī!</td>


    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Komercprogrammatūra</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Izplatāmprogrammatūra</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Brīvprogrammatūra</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bezmaksas programmatūra</td>
    </tr>


    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="Pa_Labi">

    <img src="snow-run-final.jpg">

</div>
```

Don't mind the text in the table. How do you put the picture next to the table at the top of the website?
I tried it with float, but it didn't work... maybe i made a mistake? Any help appreciated.

For some reason this website want's me to add more details to the question, so ill tell you about myself. I am 18 years old from Latvia, just started to learn how to code, and i am doing a homework for school right now. Since i want it to look pleasing as well, not just tick all the boxes teacher asked us to do, i am hereby asking for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to align the `table` and `img` next to each other.

```html
<style>
  .align-next-to-each-other {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>

<div class="align-next-to-each-other">
  <div class="Pa_Kreisi">
    <table class="greyGridTable">
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="Pa_Labi">
    <img src="snow-run-final.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were setting the width to `100%`, so the `div`s will take up the whole width. You need to set the width to `50%` or possibly smaller, so that both `div`s can fit side by side. Also, `div` elements by default are `block` elements, which means that they take up the whole width, which can be solved using `display: inline-block`.

```
<style>
.Pa_Kreisi {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: top;
}

.Pa_Labi {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: top;
}
</style>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `float`. In your question, you set one `div` to `float: left` and the other `div` to `float: right`, when they should ideally both be `float: left`.

```
<style>
.Pa_Kreisi {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: top;
}

.Pa_Labi {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: top;
}
</style>
```

---

As a side note, you are setting `height: top`, which is not valid.